# XBAP Startup Performance Improvements

Tags: wpf, performance, xbap

I have an XBAP application which is approximately 1.3MB in size. I have tried to get the size of the application down to as small as possible but have dependencies on the WPF Toolkit amongst other things and am limited there.

Currently I am experiencing slow start ups in the following areas:

- Initial Download (probably
  application size)
- Second Application run, takes a while to check version before application starts
- Application startup (Loading data &
  rendering)

What things can I do to get better startup performance for my XBAP application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to improve startup times by modifying the following areas:

- Asynchronous data loading after application startup.
- Splitting the larger DLLs into separate download groups and then downloading them asynchronously after application startup.

For anyone else interested in the second point you can read this overview on [click-once download groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak58kz04%28VS.80%29.aspx) .

Comment: how do you accomplish Asynchronous data loading